# Why is my default radio button not showing up in the model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I am have a pre-selected radio button on a form.  Here is the html:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="bankAccount.selectedAccount" value="{{account.bankAccountId}}" class="radioChanged" ng-checked="{{account.defaultAccount}}">
```

The form shows up and the radio button is selected like is should be, but when I click my submit button, the model, `bankAccount.selectedAccount`, is just an empty object.  If I click on the default radio button, which is already selected in the view, then it does show up in the model.  What do I need to do to populate my model with the default radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) instead of `value` interpolation, so that the value is associated with the model. Also note that ng-checked should not have interpolation, when you have interpolation even if the bound value is false it will be treated as "false" string and it is truthy (`If the expression is truthy, then special attribute "checked" will be set on the element`).

Try:-

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="bankAccount.selectedAccount" 
         ng-value="account.bankAccountId" class="radioChanged" 
         ng-checked="account.defaultAccount">
```

> Binds the given expression to the value of input[select] or input[radio], so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.

---

Do not mix `ng-checked` with `ng-model`, ng-checked just sets checked property of the element based on the truthy/falsy condition. It does not update ngModel. Instead if you want to select a radio then do it by  setting its ng-model  `bankAccount.selectedAccount` with the value of default account.

i.e:-

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="bankAccount.selectedAccount" 
     ng-value="account.bankAccountId" class="radioChanged" />
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r025j6?p=preview)**

Comment: The `ng-value` isn't working for me like it should.  Also I am only able to get the `ng-checked` to work if I use the curly braces.  What could be causing that?  I am using `angular 1.2.17`

Comment: @jhamm DO not use ng-checked with ng-model

Comment: I was able to make it work by setting the default in the `js` and by removing the `ng-checked`.  I also changed `value` to `ng-value` and am using it like you demonstrated.  Remove the `ng-checked` and I will select it as the correct answer.